# How to set up hybrid structure of Asp.net core 3.1 and Reactjs

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am working with ASP.NET Core 3.1 and React.js. I have a challenge in doing the Azure AD authentication in the web application. How we can set up a hybrid application in SPAs to overcome this issue.

How we can manage Azure AD authentication in React.js?

I really appreciate any help :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-initializing-client-applications Try following this tutorial to get started.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I have already checked this tutorial but i want to setup the AD Authentication in server side. Is there any solution for that?. now i am tying to set up a hybrid structure for asp.net core and react js to authenticate web app from server side.

Comment: @Maheshcm I assume by "AD" you mean Azure AD, and by hybrid application you mean a SPA + Web API, as opposed to a hybrid identity application -is that right?

Comment: @derisen yes , i am looking for the same solution., I need to authenticate the web app from server side.

Comment: @Maheshcm have a look at [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-spa-dotnetcore-webapi-obo).

Comment: @derisen thanks for the sample. For implementing this i need to have 2 AD apps for authenticating SPA and API. we have an option to configure AD authentication in azure web app registration, if i go with that approach, can i get the claimsIdentity values in server side like below given code


ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
return claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid).Value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have server side hybrid setup, you would need to follow a slightly different path. You need to create a regular asp.net core MVC web app from Visual Studio first and then wire up client side React part for SPA. I think [reactjs.net](https://reactjs.net/) is a good framework for that which saves a lot of manual effort. You can follow [this tutorial](https://reactjs.net/tutorials/aspnetcore.html). And the source code for the sample is [here](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/tree/main/src/React.Template).

Once you are done with the above app setup, then you have a regular asp.net core MVC app where you can wire up AAD auth at server side following [Microsoft Identity Web](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web#microsoft-identity-web) (depending on your scenario, you can refer the appropriate auth scenario reference/sample from there)

Comment: thanks for the solution. will check and update here